# Getting `Cannot find module 'url'` after deploying react app to production

Tags: reactjs, url, webpack, deploying

I have developed one react app from scratch by creating using `create-react-app`, and it is working well on my local env. But after deploying to production, I am getting `Cannot find module 'url'` error when trying to see all pages on the browser.
So I added 'url' to package.json, but still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is the best solution for this issue, but I think my solution will be helpful. My issue was coming from `URLSearchParams` class in my codebase.
I have used `useParams` instead of using it and removed it from my codebase, and then my deploying to production was done successfully.